# I have a table of data. In this single table i have lot of multiple data. How can i separate data by using jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

How do i separate data by using jupyter notebook.
My table name= {Table}
and inside table data was multiple like=
{

1. A,B,C,D
2. A,B,D,F
3. A,B,D,G
   }

Comment: Please show an actual (valid) Python structure as input and the required output to clarify your problem

Comment: Bear in mind that although you seem to be using Jupyter notebook as your Python development environment, you probably want to look into how Python is meant to handle what you seek. Only your tag mentions 'python' here so far when most likely every time you mention 'Jupyter notebook' in your title and question text, you probably mean 'python'. It may help to know that you can run R or Julia or all sorts of languages as the underlying kernel in a Jupyter Notebook.